# Python: Getting python class has no attribute

Tags: python

Getting below Attribute error while running below code. Class member function is accessed using self still it is giving error.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
    def f1(self):
        self.b=2
        def f2(self):
            self.c=3
            print(self.a,self.b,self.c)
        self.f2()

model = A()
model.f1()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'f2'
```

Comment: What's confusing? The class doesn't have an `f2` function.

Comment: You defined `f2()` within `f1()`, so the class itself does not know what `f2()` is.

Comment: Why do you expect `self.f2()` to be defined???

Answer (score 3):

`A` does not have an attribute `f2`, but it does have an attribute `f1` that calls a function `f2`. `f2` is not an **instance attribute**.

In this case c is no longer an instance attribute, or **data attribute**, it is now just a local variable. This may or may not be what you were 
going for.

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def f1(self):
        # Instance attribute declared outside of __init__
        self.b = 2

        def f2():
            c = 3
            print(self.a, self.b, c)
        f2()
```

Depending on your development environment you may or may not get a warning about instance attributes being declare outside of the `__init__` function. It isn't necessary that you declare them this way, however, it improves readability.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def f1(self):
        def f2():
            print(self.a, self.b, self.c)
        f2()
```

This next block is slightly more explicit in what it **says** about the intent of the code.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def f1(self):
        def f2():
            return '{} {} {}'.format(self.a, self.b, self.c)
        return f2()
```

Perhaps you want `f2()` to be called using method attributes of the 
`self` argument in which case:

```
class A2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def f2(self):
        print(self.a, self.b, self.c)

    def f1(self):
        """Do something that requires calling the self.f2()
        print function.
        """
        self.f2()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `self` when calling the nested function and nor does it need to be contained in the function signature:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
     self.a=1
   def f1(self):
     self.b=2
     def f2():
        c=3
        print(self.a,self.b, c)
     f2()

model = A()
model.f1()
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear to me that you actually need to define a function within a method just to call it.

So, your code could just as easily be this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def f1(self):
        self.b = 2
        self.f2()

    def f2(self):
        self.c = 3
        print(self.a, self.b, self.c)

model = A()
model.f1()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```